# How to change focus from a textbox to another textbox with code in WPF - C#

Tags: wpf, textbox, focus

I have Five textboxes as part of a grid.

```
<TextBox Name="A1" MaxLength="1" ></TextBox>
<TextBox Name="A2" MaxLength="1" ></TextBox>
<TextBox Name="A3" MaxLength="1" ></TextBox>
<TextBox Name="A4" MaxLength="1" ></TextBox>
<TextBox Name="A5" MaxLength="1" ></TextBox>
```

Initially cursor will be focused at A1 using the command `A1.Focus()`.
As soon as a character is entered in A1, I want the focus to be changed to A2 and then to A3 etc.
[I can enter a 5 letter word into these textboxes without pressing Tab or Enter]

How can this be done in WPF C# Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the KeyDonw event and if the key is a letter then you can change the focus.

```
<TextBox KeyDown="On_Key_Down"/>

...

On_Key_Down(object Sender, KeyEventArgs E)
{
    A2.Focus();
}
```

Comment: +1 `On_Key_Down(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) { if(e.Key != Key.Backspace) A2.Focus(); }`